# Upgrading Google API client PHP library

Tags: php, upgrade, google-api-php-client, php-7, versions

I use the PHP Google API client to authenticate users for some internal company tools and am in the processes of planning upgrading our servers from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7. Are there any versions that support both PHP versions?  v2.0.0-RC7 requires PHP 5.4 and the v1 master branch supports 5.2 and above but it isn't clear whether it supports PHP 7.

Comment: I'm Using "google/apiclient": "^2.0" with php 7 and is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As per those authentication classes there will not be any compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Google api php clinet library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) project page.  It sates the PHP requirements to use the library.

> Requirements
>
> [PHP 5.4.0 or higher](http://www.php.net/)